# Finding the Members of an External Role

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap, teradata

For Teradata databases is there some way to see which external roles I am a member of?

For a normal role I could do this:

```
SELECT * FROM DBC.RolemembersV  WHERE grantee = USER
```

This doesn't seem to work for external roles though.

Edit:
If I can't get the info with a query from Teradata, I am hoping there is some other programmatic way to extract this info from the directory (For example, Powershell).

Comment: "External role memberships" are stored in the directory (e.g. Active Directory roles or groups) and not in the database.

Comment: I kind of expected that I can't query it from the database.   However, I would still expect that I should be able to get it from the directory with a powershell script or something.  The database has to be getting the info from the directory somehow.  So there should be some programmatic way to get it, even if it isn't queryable with SQL

Comment: The database is using an API to extract who the user is information and what their group memberships are from the inbound token that originally authenticated against the DB.  That token resides in memory rather than in the DB itself which is why SQL queries don't find this information.

Comment: There are multiple potential ways to map AD entries to External Roles (controlled via search patterns in tdgssconfig on the database nodes). You would need to know the pattern being used to identify roles, or group membership; and for groups whether nested groups are being used. Then you could use those same patterns for AD queries. There is a _tdgssauth_ command on the database nodes that can be used for debugging.